# Crystal Report Logon Failed

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to print my report, but when i set server = (IP)\SQLEXPRESS always fail to logon, in management studio work fine. and if i set server = .\SQLEXPRESS it's working. why can't I use the ip to connect report to database?

```
public class PrintService : IPrintService
{
    readonly ReportDocument _reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

    private readonly string _reportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportPath"];
    private readonly string _reportUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportUser"];
    private readonly string _reportPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportPassword"];
    private readonly string _reportServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"];
    private readonly string _reportDatabase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportDatabase"];
    private readonly string _spbuNumber = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SPBUNumber"];
    private readonly string _spbuAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SPBUAddress"];
    private readonly string _spbuPhone = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SPBUPhone"];

    public void Print(string number, string reportName)
    {
        var path = _reportPath + reportName;
        _reportDocument.Load(path);
        _reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(_reportUser, _reportPassword, _reportServer, _reportDatabase);
        _reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Number", number);
        _reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Location", _spbuNumber );
        _reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Address", _spbuAddress);
        _reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Phone", _spbuPhone);
        var print = new PrintDocument();
        _reportDocument.PrintOptions.PrinterName = print.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        _reportDocument.PrintOptions.PaperSize = (PaperSize) print.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind;
        _reportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: SQL server browser service is not working?

Comment: do you have remote connections turned on for that SQL Server Express?

Comment: Arva : SQL browser service is running, it's work if i verify database on .rpt and input server (IP)\SQLEXPRESS. but it's not good solution :(

Comment: Andrew : Remote Connections?

Comment: Remote connections:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx  By default, they are not turned on for SQL Server Express.

Comment: remote connection is enable, login success to server, only crystal report fail to logon. @.@

Answer (score 0):

IS (IP) is server namme or ip adress , id Ip is server name then remove the brackets. Or use direct ip address of that server.

Answer (score 0):

To load a report at runtime, on a client pc,  I needed to fish out the connection string to find the client's local server name . I tried different ways to alter a crystal report form logon connection , but only this worked for me.This is on the latest 13.0.9.1312.Cortez_CR4VS version, with the windows form version inside WPF.
In this code prepap is the full Crystal reportname, including the path and dbName just the name of the attached SQL database. csName is from the app.config: string from add name.   New connection is saved in the report.

```
ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
String CS = (String)ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[csName].ConnectionString;
doc.Load(prerap);
String DS = CS.Substring(12 + CS.IndexOf("data source"), CS.IndexOf("SQLEXPRESS") - CS.IndexOf("data source") - 2);
            if (doc.DataSourceConnections[0].ServerName != DS)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<doc.DataSourceConnections.Count;i++) 
                {
                    doc.DataSourceConnections[i].SetConnection(DS, dbName, true);               
                }

                doc.SaveAs(prerap);

            }
```